# React Native Bold Font Family not Working

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, fonts

I am making use of nunitosans font library but only the regular font works on the mobile app,

this is the content on my react-native.config.js file,

[image]

I already ran npx react-native link but other font weights are not working such as bold

Android file structure

[image]

the screen on the mobile app where **the bold font family is not been applied**

[image]

Text Components

[image]

> The bold and semibold font family are not working, only the regular
> font family works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the fontWeight property from Text style made it work

Comment: How do you make it bold when you remove fontWeight?

Answer (score 4):

in my case, i avoid using `fontWeight` property but instead change the font to its bold version. there is unsolved [issues](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/26193) for ReactNative

So i would make my styling like this:

```js
const styles = Stylesheet.create({
  fontNormal:{
    fontFamily: aFontName
  },
  fontBold:{
    fontFamily: aFontName-Bold
  }
})
```